# Загрузить страницу на хостинг

Tags: bootstrap, хостинг

Есть шаблон страницы созданной на bootstrap и эту страницу нужно как-нибудь загрузить на хостинг, как это сделать?

Comment: @Vest, хостинг-то уже имеется?

Comment: Да, Hostinger

Comment: Вот тут расписали как работать с фтп http://www.hostinger.ru/baza-znaniy/686

Answer (score 1):

1. Скачать FTP-клиент
2. Подключиться
3. Закачать файлы
4. Profit?

Comment: Для чайника сложновато, может разжевать сможешь?